# how to make xlwings faster or find another alternative?

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

My problem is this:
I have an Excel file with 8000 rows and 80 columns.
I import the excel file with pandas. I make some calculations and treatments on the pandas dataframe.I can handle pandas without any problems. So far so good.
Then I open an excel file with xlwings and paste my dataframe values on the excel file where I make a condition on the colors.  For example paste only the white color cells (rgb=(255,255,255)). This is why I use xlwings instead of pd.to_excel because I can always keep the format of my basic excel file (colors, etc...).

```
example of code : ws is the worksheet and df the dataframe


 import xlwings as xw
    xw.App(visible=False,spec=None, impl=None).screen_updating=False
    wb=xw.Book('input_path')
    wb.app.calculation='manual'
    ws=wb.sheets['sheet1']
    rgb_tuple=(255,255,255)
    for i in range(80000):
        for j in range(80):
            if ws.range((i+1,j+1)).color==rgb_tuple:
                  ws.range((i+1,j+1))=df.iloc[i,j]
    wb.save('output_name')
    wb.close()
    xw.screen_updating=True
```

**NB: this code is just an example of what i do**

It's take more than 30 minutes to run. It's so slow more than VBA.
I use screen_updating=False and visible=False. I hoped that this would help but it's still very slow.
Please, do you know an option to put on xlwings to make it faster or another library that does the same job but faster?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You must not loop through single cells, instead, build a nested list in Python, then write this to Excel 1 operation, e.g. `ws.range((1,1)).value = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]`

Comment: Thanks @Felix Zumstein , if i do this ws.range((1,1)).value = [[1, 2], [3, 4]], how can i take into account a condition like ws.range((1,1)).color=(255,255,255)?. I want to paste values only in excel cells with a white fill. Coloured cells have formulas and I don't want to crush them. That's why I make a condition to paste only on the white cells.

Comment: You can read in the formulas by using `myrange.formula`, then you can assign a mix of values and formulas back via `myrange.value = ['=A1+C2', 2]` (the first cell is a formula, the second a value). This way you won't crush them. Working with color is complicated as you indeed need to loop through every cell.

Comment: If someone have the same problem looping through cells with openpyxl  is faster than xlwings. "If ws.cell(row=row, column=col).fill.start_color.tint==0.0" can help you find the right cell color. In general you can use ws.cell(row=row, column=col).fill.start_color attributes. Hope it's will help. Without looping through cells, xlwings is very good and easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to speed up **reading** multiple cells at once  with xlwings (for example if you want to iterate row by row) you can use `sheet.range()` that returns `xlwings.Range` object and then access all range values at once with `raw_value` property:

```py
import xlwings as xw

for row in range(1, 10000):
   r = sheet.range((row, 2), (row, 45))
   values = [r.raw_value[0][x] for x in [1,2,3,7,8,9]]
```

`raw_value` is tuple of tuples representing rows and columns with apropriately mapped types (`float`, `str`, etc).

Documentation: https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/api.html#xlwings.Range